# Divisibility of discriminants in number field extensions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a tower of number fields.

If $e_1,\dots,e_n$ and $m_1,\dots,m_k$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-bases of the ring of integers of $L$ and $K$, then
$$d_L=\det(\text{tr}(e_ie_j)), \ d_K=\det(\text{tr}(m_im_j)).$$
We can write $m_i=\sum a_{ik} e_k$ for some $a_{ij}\in\mathbb{Z}$, so
$$d_K=\det(\text{tr}(m_im_j))=\det\left(\sum a_{ik}a_{jl} \text{tr}(e_ke_l)\right)=\det(a_{ij})^2 d_L.$$
**But this must be wrong:** consider a cyclotomic field, whose discriminant has a *square factor*. It contains (by Galois theory) a quadratic field, whose discriminant is *squarefree* when it is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ with $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$)

Where is the mistake ?

Comment: One thing that looks a bit fishy is that you need to use the trace for K/Q, not L/Q, in defining the discriminant of K.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Reposted as an answer as suggested by @QiL'8) (EDIT: This is wrong, see below)

The reason your argument is a little fishy is that the trace map for the extension $K / \mathbf{Q}$ is not the same as the restriction to $K$ of the trace for $L / \mathbf{Q}$; in fact the two differ by a factor of $[L : K]$. The formula that actually comes out is

$$ [L : K]^2 d_K = \det(a_{ij})^2 d_L $$

which is no contradiction.

EDIT. Revisiting this 2 years later prompted by A.P.'s comments, it seems that this is wrong as well. On closer inspection, the manipulation in the question is meaningless, because the matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ is not a square matrix, so $\det(A)$ does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure about this? [We have](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1282723/65389) $\mathfrak{d}_{L/\Bbb{Q}} = \mathfrak{d}_{K/\Bbb{Q}}^{[L:K]} N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{d}_{L/K})$ where $\mathfrak{d}_{A/B}$ is the discriminant ideal of the extension $A/B$. Since $\mathfrak{d}_{L/\Bbb{Q}}=(d_L)$ and $\mathfrak{d}_{K/\Bbb{Q}}=(d_K)$, doesn't this imply that $d_K^{[L:K]} \mid d_L$ (which doesn't seem to follow from your formula)?

Comment: I'm not convinced. By definition $\mathfrak{d}_{K/\Bbb{Q}}$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$, thus principal, say generated by $g$. Now, $N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}$ sends ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ in ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$, so $N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{d}_{K/\Bbb{Q}})$ looks like an abuse of notation. Even ignoring this, $N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(g\Bbb{Z}) = \left( N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(g\mathcal{O}_K) = \right)  N_{K/\Bbb{Q}}(g) \Bbb{Z} = g^{[K:\Bbb{Q}]} \Bbb{Z}$. Then your formula implies that $d_K = | g^{[K:\Bbb{Q}]} |$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Ah, that's the reason of the misunderstanding! I'm using the notation of Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, where $\mathfrak{d}_{K/\Bbb{Q}}$ denotes the *discriminant* ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ over $\Bbb{Z}$, not the different (which Neukirch denotes $\mathfrak{D}_{K\Bbb{Q}}$).

Comment: In particular, for a finite separable field extension $F/G$, $\mathfrak{d}_{F/G}$ is defined as the ideal of $\mathcal{O}_G$ generated by the discriminants $d(\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n) = \det(Tr(\alpha_i\alpha_j))$ for $\{\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n\}$ ranging over all the bases of $F$ over $G$ with elements in $\mathcal{O}_F$. As you suggest, it can then be proved (Neukirch's theorem III.2.9) that $\mathfrak{d}_{F/G} = N_{F/G}(\mathfrak{D}_{F/G})$.

Comment: You are right, this was wrong. I've edited my answer.