# Discriminant of Number Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ and $F$ be two number fields of degree $n$ and $m$ and $K\cap F = \mathbb{Q}$. Then we consider the number field $KF$ generated by $K$ and $F$. It is known that we have the relation between corresponding discriminant, i.e,
$$ d_{KF}\ \Big|\ d_K^m\cdot d_F^n. $$
If $p$ is ramified in $KF$ and umramified in $F$. Can we get the following identity for $p$-part of discriminants?
$$d_{KF,p} = d_{K,p}^m.$$

Any help is welcome and appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the fields $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2})$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8\sqrt[4]{2})$, where $\zeta_8$ is the fourth root of unity. It's not hard to see that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the only real subfield of $F$ and so we have that $K \cap F = \mathbb{Q}$, as $K$ is a real subfield.

Now using [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) one can calculate that $d_F=2^{11}$, while $d_K=2^{11}3^{6}$. On the otherside $KF = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2}+\zeta_8\sqrt[4]{2})$. The minimal polynomial of the primitive element according to Wolfram Alpha is $x^{12} - 6x^8 + 48x^7 - 4x^6 + 12x^4 + 160x^3 + 168x^2 + 48x - 4$. Again by PARI/GP we get that $d_{KF} = -2^{35}3^{12}$ and hence we have that the $p$-parts aren't the same.

The reason why this happens is that $K \cap F = \mathbb{Q}$ isn't enough to conclude that $KF$ is an extension of degree $mn$. Indeed if one of the fields is Galois then this would be true. In fact it's enough for $K$ to have a trivial intersection with the Galois closure of $F$ or vice versa. Note that this isn't the case, as $K \cap F_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, while $K_1 \cap F = \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$, where $K_1$ and $F_1$ are the respective Galois closures.

If the condition from above is satisfied we have that the claim is true. You can use the theorem in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282542/transitivity-of-the-discriminant-of-number-fields). It's not hard to notice that $d_{KF/K} \mid d_F$ (as ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$) and then we have that 
$$N(d_{KF/F}) \text{ }\Big | \text{ }N(d_F) = d_F^n$$

The last equality follows, as $d_F$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence $N(d_{KF/F})$ doesn't contribute with any $p$-factor and so we have that the $p$-part of $d_{KF}$ is same as the one of $d_{K}^m$

---

**[UPDATE]:** In fact we can do most of the proof without those computer aided calculations. Consider $K,F$ as above and let $L=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$. Then it's not hard to conclude that $KF = KL$. Indeed $KL \subseteq KF$ and the equality holds as they have the same extension degree over $\mathbb{Q}$, namely $12$. Now we have that $d_{KL} \mid d_{K}^2d_{L}^6$. It's easy to see that $3 \mid d_K$, while not being a factor of $d_L$

Similarly $d_{KL} = d_{KF} \mid d_{K}^4d_{F}^6$ and $3 \nmid d_F$. Finally from above we have that $d_{KF}$ and $d_K^4$ can't have the same $p$-parts.

Comment: Very careful explanation! Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas You are welcome :)