# Discriminant of a non separable extension

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Why is the discriminant of a non separable finite extension of a field $0$? I proved for the case when the extension is primitive but can't prove it for the general case. Can trying to use induction help?

Comment: What is your definition of discriminant?

Answer (score 0):

Let $L/K$ be non-separable. By [Stacks 030K](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030K), the set of elements in $L$ that are separable over $K$ form an intermediate extension $L^s/K$ that is separable, and $L/L^s$ is purely inseparable ([Stacks 09HE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09HE)).

It then suffices to address the case where $L/K$ is purely inseparable (by letting $K := L^s$), by [this formula about discriminants and towers of fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1282723/328173).

By [Stacks 09HI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09HI), one can factorize $L/K$ into a tower $L = E_n / \cdots / E_2 / E_1 / E_0 = K$ where each $E_{i+1}/E_i$ is degree $p$ and purely inseparable and is formed by adjoining the $p$<sup>th</sup> root of some element in $E_i$. By the same formula quoted above, it suffices to address the case where $L/K$ is one of these steps in the tower.

So let $L = K(a^{1/p})$ for some $a \in K \setminus K^p$. The minimal polynomial of $a^{1/p}$ over $K$ is $f(x) = x^p - a$, so the discriminant of $L/K$ is $f'(a^{1/p}) = p \cdot a^{(p-1)/p} = {\fbox{0}}$, as required. Note that this last step depends on your definition of discriminant.

Comment: $Disc(a_1,\ldots,a_m)=\det(A^\top A)=0$ for any $K$-basis of $L$ because $A_{ij}=\sigma_j(a_i)$ where each $\sigma_j\in Hom_K(L,\overline{L})$ is repeated $[L:L^s]$ times so that $\det(A)=0$.

Comment: @reuns why not post another answer

Comment: Hi, so my definition of discriminant is the discriminant of a particular set of basis elements, which is what you have seemed to use. Thank you for the answer.